# Receiving message in AT commands not working

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command

I am using sim 900a modem. I want to read the messages coming to this modem. I have enabled the text mode AT+CMGF=1; I am sending message:

http://www.hughes.com/AT_Command_Reference.html#AT_plusCMGF

but I am receiving in this format...

```
  +CMT: "+919841675265","","14/06/14,12:04:14+22"                                 
   0068007400740070003A002F002F006D006100700073002E0067006F006F0067006C0065002E0068

  +CMT: "+919841675265","","14/06/14,12:04:17+22"                                 
  00200020002000540069006D0065003A00310034003A00330033003A003400340020002000440067
```

If I send the same message from another phone, I am receiving correctly....

I cant find where the problem is... please help me on this.

Comment: When you set the modem to text mode what answer do you get from the modem? An OK? Also did your modem restart between setting text mode and receiving an SMS?

Comment: yes. and i checked it AT+CMGF? i got AT+CMGF=1 ... i cant find the exact problem...the same message is sent from my mobile, i receiving it properly... but sent from other mobiles i receiving it like this

Comment: So after the AT+CMGF=1 was echoed back there was also a OK answer from the mobile also. Correct?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe is because of the codepage you are using.

With the AT command AT+CSCS try to set your codepage in IRA or GSM.

Example: AT+CSCS="IRA"

Comment: Very likely. Also try with "UTF-8" (or some of the other character sets given by `AT+CSCS=?`).